# NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable for jqgrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid, http-status-code-406

I have a jqgrid to populate data which is coming from backend. Till controller i have data but its not getting rendered in grid.Enabling Fire bug says **NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable**.
I have **jackson-core-asl-1.x.jar** and **jackson-mapper-asl-1.x.jar** in my classpath  and  in dispatcher aservlet. 
I have also tried to change header according to one of solution as headers="Accept=application/json".I am using SPring4. Following is my code in controller.

`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/populateAddedDeviceGrid.html", headers="Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    GridPojo populateAddedDeviceGrid(HttpServletRequest request, GridPojo gridPojo) {
        System.out.println("Enetering DeviceMasterController-->populateAddedDeviceGrid (POST)");

        List<DeviceMaster> deviceMasterList = new ArrayList<DeviceMaster>();

        try {
            deviceMasterList = deviceMasterService.getAllDeviceMaster();


            gridPojo.setGridData(deviceMasterList.toArray());
            gridPojo.setRows(deviceMasterList.size());
            gridPojo.setRecords(deviceMasterList.size());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return gridPojo;
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/populateAddedDeviceGrid.html", headers="Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//-------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

here instead of `headers` should be used `produces` something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/populateAddedDeviceGrid.html", produces={"application/json"} , method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: It did not solved my problem , i tried using **@RequestMapping(value = "/populateAddedDeviceGrid.html", produces="application/json" , method = RequestMethod.POST)** . but still gives me 406 http error